# How to mutate a column in a dataframe dynamically in R

Tags: r, tidyeval

I want to mutate the value of a `dataframe`/`tibble` column defined as a variable (`col_name`). I tried with `!!col_name` without success.

```
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
col_name <- "b" # the column to select

df <- tibble(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(2,4,6))

df %>%
  mutate(b = if_else((b == 6 & a == 3), 8, b))  # this works 
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       a     b
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     2     4
#> 3     3     8

# but this doesn't
df %>%
  mutate(!!col_name := if_else((!!col_name == 6 & a == 3), 8, !!col_name))
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `b`.
#> x `false` must be a double vector, not a character vector.
#> i Input `b` is `if_else(("b" == 6 & a == 3), 8, "b")`.
Created on 2020-10-13 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `!!` on RHS you need to first convert `col_name` to symbol.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(!!col_name := if_else(!!sym(col_name) == 6 & a == 3, 
                            8, !!sym(col_name)))
```

Other alternatives include using `get` :

```
df %>% mutate(!!col_name := if_else(get(col_name) == 6 & a == 3,
                             8, get(col_name)))
```

Or without any NSE use `.data` :

```
df %>% mutate(!!col_name := if_else(.data[[col_name]] == 6 & a == 3, 
                            8, .data[[col_name]]))
```

Comment: Any of the three methods is preferable?

Comment: Lionel (package author of `rlang`) recently stated that using `.data` is preferred method now. This should also be mentioned somewhere in rlang/tidyverse website.

Answer (score 3):

Using *base*:

```
df[ df[, col_name ] == 6 & df$a == 3, col_name ] <- 8

df
#   a b
# 1 1 2
# 2 2 4
# 3 3 8
```

**Note:** Yes, I am aware that the question is about *"tidy"*, this is just to illustrate why for some simple tasks base solutions are just as good/better.