# Multiple plots using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I am trying to print out and save to ggplot2 object (with a proper name with may change for each element of p.vec) using for loops, any help will be appreciated, many thanks in advance.

```
 par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
    p.vec <- c("disp","mpg")
    for(i in p.vec){
    p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y= i)) +geom_jitter()
    print(p)
    #ggsave("plot.pdf")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `lapply` :

```
library(ggplot2)
p.vec <- c("disp","mpg")

lapply(p.vec, function(x) {
  p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y= .data[[x]])) +geom_jitter()
  ggsave(sprintf('plot_%s.jpg', x))
})
```

Instead of `.data[[x]]` you can also use any of the option from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64333423/3962914) answer.